# How to use loop to read, add col and merge in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have several CSVs, and I want to read it and select specific columns, then add a year number to each and last merge it together.

for example, I have a data as 2003.csv, 2004.csv, 2005.csv
And I want to read them, then select A,B,C column
Next, add the year, same as the file name, at last, merge it. I know How do it one by one, like this:

```
d2003 <- read.csv("2003.csv",stringsAsFactors=F)
n2003 <- d2003[,c("A", "B","C"]
n2003$year <- rep(2003,nrow(n2003))
```

I got n2003 and then n2004.....last, merge it together
But I don't know how to do it in the loop. As far, I know how to read in loops

```
rdata <- list()
list_file <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
for (k in 1:length(list_file)){
  rdata[[k]] <- read.csv(list_file[k],stringsAsFactors=F)
}
```

Then I was stucked....

Comment: What are the columns and types of each CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following script:

```
years <- c("2003", "2004", "2005")
df <- NA
sapply(years, function(x) {
                 filename <- paste0(x, ".csv")
                 df.next <- read.csv(filename, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
                 df.next$year <- as.numeric(x)
                 if (is.na(df)) {  
                    df <- df.next
                 } else {
                    df <- rbind(df, df.next)
                 }
              })
```

You had a few minor problems with your original attempt.  The following line is redundant:

```
n2003$year <- rep(2003,nrow(n2003))
```

This is redundant because `n2003$year <- 2003` already will assign `2003` to the entire column.  Another possibly issue is that you were looping over a list, when you could use an `apply()` function to do that.